# Display HTML5 jQuery Audio Player On Front Page

Tags: plugins, shortcode, templates, audio

I would like to display the plugin *HTML5 jQuery Audio Player* 'centered' on the front page of my site. The plugin comes with shortcodes for posts and pages but my front(home page) only works with the `'set front page to posts'` option.

I'm new to this coding business, so I guess I need to call the plugin from the `index.php` template file.

Comment: Hi, Jay, welcome to the code business! Please, take a look at this site [faq] and use your profile for signatures and such.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin has shortcodes, then you can use the function [**`do_shortcode`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) to display it within a theme file.

It'd be a case of:

```
<div class="align-center"><?php do_shortcode( "[audio-player title='Lorem Ipsum']" ); ?></div>
```

Comment: do_shortcode() normally works for this sort of thing; but the plugin referenced in the author's question does not.